# In Java can I listen for an action to occur in one class then take a parallel action?

Tags: java

I need to monitor for an error that is occurring in a particular method in a Java class that cannot be changed because it is owned by a third party.
This method gets invoked by a particular feature within the system that will end up causing several hoops to be jumped in order to fix it (because only
a generic error is written to the UI and logs - we will pursue getting the owner of the class (an external vendor) to fix it, but it will likely take while).

As a workaround, I have de-compiled the class and added logger statements that print the data elements that are causing the issue. This can be run
externally and only when granted permission to do so, and cannot be put in the Production environment (because of contract and other issues).

Is it possible to "listen" for this method being called without actually editing the original class? Or is there some other suitable workaround I am not thinking of?

Comment: I think this might be an XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Can you give some broader idea of what you need this for?

Comment: The problem is that an error is occurring in Class A, which was written by a vendor. The error is only reported generically to the UI and app log. Every time this error occurs, I have to use a decompiled version of Class A with logger statements that I added to find the element of data that is causing the issue.  This involves getting at least 2 people involved, for access rights and other things.  We can't deploy the decompiled version because of contact issues, so I'd like another solution.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
I agree with [Paul Boddington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3973077/paul-boddington) that this might be an XY problem. You can use one of the solutions below, but perhaps you have a different problem than you describe. You might want to reconsider the thing you actually want to achieve.

---

You have several options:

- You can subclass class 'A', and then when the event occurs, notify registered listeners, like this:

  ```
  public class SubA extends A {

      private AListener listener;

      public void method1() {
          if (this.listener != null) {
              this.listener.notifyMethodCall();
          }
          super.method1();
      }

      public void setAListener(AListener listener) {
          this.listener = listener;
      }
  }
  ```

  And the `AListener` interface:

  ```
  public interface AListener {

      void notifyMethodCall();

  }
  ```

  Class `B`:

  ```
  public class B implements AListener {

      public B(A a) {
          a.setAListener(this);
      }

      public void notifyMethodCall() {
          // Do whatever you want.
      }
  }
  ```
- If the method call `A.method1()` changes an attribute of itself, you could check its value interval-based, for example, each second check its value, but that's generally bad in this context.

*It can be that class `A` cannot be overridden because it is a `final` class, but that's generally considered as a bad design. The `String` class is, however, an exception.*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Bottom line is I don't have control of Class A and it is generating an error that isn't handled well. I can't edit Class A and it will continue executing as-is for now, but I'd like to work in parallel to write the data out that's causing the issue (or cause my subclass to be executed instead of Class A).  it sounds like your solution requires me to implement my subclass of A as the class that gets executed in place of Class A, correct?  If so, that won't work, because this involves a system from a vendor we aren't allowed to change (but long term will pursue a fix).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe you can also do it with an [AOP listener](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/simple-introduction-to-aop.html).  You can define advice before an event happens, during, or after.